# Need guidance on how to build a Laravel database query

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 6.18 I'm trying to figure out how to recreate the following Postgres query.

```
with data as (
    select date_trunc('month', purchase_date) as x_month,  date_trunc('year', purchase_date) AS x_year,
    sum (retail_value) AS "retail_value_sum" 
    from coins 
    where user_email = 'user@email.com' and sold = 0
    group by x_month, x_year
    order by x_month asc, x_year asc
)
select x_month, x_year, sum (retail_value_sum) over (order by x_month asc, x_year asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row)
from data
```

I know how to build the main part of the query

```
$value_of_all_purchases_not_sold = DB::table('coins')
    ->select(DB::raw('date_trunc(\'month\', purchase_date) AS x_month, date_trunc(\'year\', purchase_date) AS x_year, sum(retail_value) as purchase_price_sum'))
    ->where('user_email', '=', auth()->user()->email)
    ->where('sold', '=', 0)
    ->groupBy('x_month', 'x_year')
    ->orderBy('x_month', 'asc')
    ->orderBy('x_year', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

but how do you build out the **with data as (** and the second **select**?

I need the data to be cumulative and I'd rather do the calculation in the DB than in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel doesn't have built-in method(s) for `common table expression`. You may use a third party package such as [this](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-cte) - it has a very good documentation. If you don't want to use an external library, then you need use query builder's `select` method with bindings such as

```
$results = DB::select('your-query', ['your', 'bindings']);

return Coin::hydrate($results); // if you want them as collection of Coin instance.
```